# Not getting +100 rep for account association

Tags: status-completed

Generally when I join a stackExchange site in beta it gives me a bonus 100 reputation to get started.  Right now I am starting at 1 reputation.  Is there a reason for this?  Is this intended behavior?

Comment: I don't know about the reputation bridge, but there shouldn't be anything that prevents a new user from posting questions and answers. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @phu There is on SE beta metas; you need 5 rep to post questions or answers

Comment: oh thanks I didn't know that :)

Comment: There, you got it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not intended behavior, you should be getting +100. I tried reassociating your accounts and recalculating your rep, but it's not working; your log doesn't even show the account association happening. I tried creating a new account on an SE I haven't been on and got the same problem, so I [filed a bug about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100). Unfortunately there's nothing I can do in the meantime (I can't give you +100 rep); hopefully it doesn't affect you too much and it'll be fixed soon

---

**Edit**: [One of the SO devs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6/kevin-montrose) posted this on the bug report:

> There's a bug in some new associations code (that went out last night) that prevents the current account from gaining the association bonus. This has been fixed on dev, and should go out tonight.
>
> The work around for now is to establish the association from one of your other accounts (may require clearing before hand).

If you want the bonus now you can do the workaround ([clear your associations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2650?tab=accounts) here, go to another site, and associate with Unix that way), or just wait until the fix goes out and you can reassociate from here

Comment: This explains a lot. I had the same problems. Just on Friday it was working quite well. But yesterday half the features vanished and you cannot associate single accounts anymore. It's all or nothing now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on your answer or the question so I add an answer to say this : The same happened to me.

EDIT : I just received my +100 rep.